# Protractor loggingPrefs, how to start and stop recording performance logs after certain test step and stop it once its done

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using loggingPrefs in my test to log all network call/ http request made during the test, I want to know if its possible to log performance logs after certain test step and stop it once that step is done. so that I can validate that certain Http request have been made after the step is executed.

For e.g. :

```
//Start Recording Performance after user is logged in
//and validate certain HTTP request is made
//Stop Recording Performance 
//Log out from application - I do not want to record performance for Logout step
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job. Adapt the code to your needs. Do not forget to attach the browser

capabilities:

```
'goog:chromeOptions': {
    'perfLoggingPrefs': {
        'enableNetwork': true,
        'enablePage': false
    }
},
loggingPrefs: {
 'performance': 'ALL'
}
```

Example spec:

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

describe('dummy test', () => {
    it('should do something', async () => {
        const startTime = Date.now();

        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await browser.get('https://google.com');

        await browser.sleep(5000);

        const endTime = Date.now();

        await collectPerformLog(startTime, endTime);
    });
});

export async function collectPerformLog(timeFrom, timeTo) {
    await browser.manage().logs().get('performance').then((browserLog) => {

        const fs = require('fs-extra');
        const filePath = '/performance/performance.log';
        fs.ensureDirSync('/performance/');
        let filteredData = browserLog
            .filter(data => timeFrom < data.timestamp && timeTo > data.timestamp);
        fs.appendFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(filteredData));

    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error collection performance logs.', e);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this but FilteredData does not contain anything, performance.log is getting created as empty file with [].

Comment: did you add the capabilities in protractor ?

Comment: check browserLog, if its empty, means you forget to enable something in the capabilities, otherwise the date - from/to you provide for filter does not match the timestamp of the logged data.

Comment: I tried couple of things `browser.manage().logs().get('performance').then((browserLogs) => { var filteredData = browserLogs.filter(data => timeFrom < data.timestamp && timeTo > data.timestamp);});` this does not work but If I write it this way it works :  `browserLogs.forEach((browserLog) => {
        var message = JSON.parse(browserLog.message).message; console.log(message.params.request.url, browserLog.timestamp);});`

Comment: The timestamp your provide, for filtering data its NOT matching the real data from the browser logs. Be sure the timestamp - start is BEFORE the requests, and end timestamp is when you wish to reduce the browser logs. Script is working perfectly just you have to properly apply date timestamp

Comment: there are the timestamps I am getting from `Date.now();` `TimeFrom === 1571692387746
TimeTO ==== 1571692387747`  and `console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData));` is retuned as '[]'

Comment: Do you think in that 1ms, there was some request data loggedi n the browser. Compare the actual log timestamp and the filter time you provide...

Comment: Figured out the problem, `const endTime = Date.now();` was getting executed before `browser.sleep(5000);` hence there was just 1ms difference between the start and end time. I moved endTime to `export async function collectPerformLog(timeFrom) {
    await browser.manage().logs().get('performance').then((browserLog) => {
const endTime = Date.now();
` and this fixed my problem.